# How to match any word in parenthesis but with 2 capital letters at least?

Tags: r, regex

From this text:

```
[1] "Percentage of Participants Who Achieved a 75% Improvement (Response) in the Psoriasis Area Severity Index (PASI-75) at Week 16 From Baseline"                                                                 
[3] "Percentage of Participants Who Achieved a Static Physician Global Assessment (sPGA) Score of Clear (0) or Almost Clear (1) With at Least 2 Points Reduction From Baseline"                                    
[15] "Change From Baseline in the Mental Component Summary (MSC) Score of the Medical Outcome Study Short Form 36-item (SF-36) Health Survey Version 2.0 at Week 16"
```

I want to match: PASI-75, sPGA, MSC, SF-36, so not 'Response', not (1) nor (0).
The regex I want use should be something like:
`\([a-zA-Z0-9-]*&[A-Z]{2,}\)` but don't know how to express `&` here. Some thread suggested `(?=query1)(?=query2)` but it doesn't work here.

Comment: Looks like R, doesn't it? Try [`\([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/FjOUWg/1).

Comment: What language/flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for quick response. I'm not sure where's AND but it's ok.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Same comment as to Isaac Truett's answer: You are constraining the capitals to be consecutive.

Comment: Are you ok with the `(` and `)` in the matches, or do you want to get the value without the brackets?

Comment: Brackets no problem. Without would be: `(?<=\()[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=\))`. It's working, thanks.

Comment: Or [`pat <- "(?<=\\()[[:alnum:]-]*[[:upper:]]{2}[[:alnum:]-]*(?=\\))"` ; `unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pat, x, perl=TRUE)))`](http://ideone.com/C1xWtS)

Answer (score 3):

Try `\([^\)]*[A-Z]{2}[^\)]*\)`

This matches a `(`, zero or more non-`)` characters, two upper-case letters, zero or more non-`)` characters, and a `)`.

An alternative that allows for non-consecutive capitals, but still restricts to matching a single word:

`\([^\)]*[A-Z][^\)]*[A-Z][^\)]*\)`

This matches a `(`, zero or more non-`)` characters, one upper-case letter, zero or additional non-`)` characters, one upper-case letter, zero or more non-`)` characters, and a `)`.

Comment: Only problem is that this forces the capitals to be consecutive. I would recommend `\([^\(]*[A-Z][^\)]*[A-Z][^\)]*\)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's a good point. I was inferring intent as identifying acronyms in parenthesis. There are plenty of other unspecified scenarios, I'm sure.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Also, your proposed edit matches too much, such as `(Response) in the Psoriasis Area Severity Index (PASI-75)` in the first line.

Comment: @Peter.k Where is this answer lacking?

Comment: It's the issue posted above @MadPhysicist

Comment: @IsaacTruett. That is because I accidentally wrote `^\(` instead of `^\)` for my match group (as did you).

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit that I made, since you included my change.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Don't mind edits, but I think in this case you introduced a bug: it fails the "single word" test. It will match `(Mad Hatter)` for example, because it contains two capital letters. I kept iterating on the regex and got this far: `\([a-z0-9-]*[A-Z][a-z0-9-]*[A-Z]{1,}[a-z0-9-]*\)`. But, really, I could tweak the regex all day and it doesn't get anywhere if the simpler form is "good enough" for the current use case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (from your example) you want to match any non-whitespace character enclosed within parenthesis, I would say that the simplest solution will be:

```
\(\S*[A-Z]{2}\S*\)
```

Answer (score -2):

What you want is [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html). 
The regex engine will first try to match two capital letters.
Like this:

```
\b\((?=[A-Z]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\b
```

(?=[A-Z]{2}) tells the engine to look for two capitals first.
It will skip the whole word if it can't find two capitals.

Comment: You are constraining the capitals to be consecutive.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, the main issue with this approach is that the two uppercase letters are required right after `(` and word boundaries will only let matching `(...)` when enclosed with word chars. Rather unexpected, I'd say.

Comment: I' ve noticed some backslashes weren't shown in the text. I did put backslashes in front of the parantheses to make them literals. I've put the regex in a code line. Now they're visible.